# Promise not working inside recursion function

Tags: node.js, recursion, promise

- i'm trying to create a function to check exist and not exist file names so i used recursion function and proimse but unfortunately it's not resolve anything when the condition is true i tried it like that

```
function checkFileName(n = 0) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.open("./npm"+n+".txt", 'r', function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                resolve("./npm"+n+".txt")
            } else {
                n++
                checkFileName(n)
            }
        })
    })
}
checkFileName().then(Name => {
    console.log(Name)
})
```

but it's not resolve anything where's the wrong ?

Comment: You're never resolving the top level promise if you go in the `else` part. [Recursive auto increment function in not resolving](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61009255)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change `checkFileName(n)` to `checkFileName(n).then(resolve)`

One of the solutions would be as follows:

```
function checkFileName(n = 0) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const filePath = "./npm"+n+".txt";
        fs.open(filePath, 'r', function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                resolve(filePath)
            } else {
               checkFileName(n+1).then(resolve)
            }
        })
    })
}
checkFileName().then(Name => {
    console.log(Name)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Any specific reason you is doing it like that ?

```
// Node.js program to demonstrate the 
// fs.readdir() method 

  
// Import the filesystem module 

const fs = require('fs'); 

const path = require('path'); 

  
// Function to get current filenames 
// in directory with specific extension 
fs.readdir(__dirname, (err, files) => { 

  if (err) 

    console.log(err); 

  else { 

    console.log("\Filenames with the .txt extension:"); 

    files.forEach(file => { 

      if (path.extname(file) == ".txt") 

        console.log(file); 

    }) 

  } 
})
```

Instead of reading a file at the time, you can read the hole dir and iterate over them returned files

Comment: you aren't understand me good i don't want to show all files with .txt extention i want to check if this file name is exist or not and if it's already exist i will generate a new filename with the same name but change the number for example i have `npm0.txt`, `npm1.txt` i want this recursion function generate number untill found not exist file who is in this case `npm2.txt` that's what i done but i was need to get it out of the `open()` function so i used promise but it wasn't resolve anything because i wasn't handle the promise everytime i make a recursion so i handled it and it's working now

Comment: Seems like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876). I'd recommend something non-recursive like this answer, even/especially with the requirement clarification, although I'd recommend using promises all the way through, no callbacks. Mixing promises and callbacks as you're doing, and as the accepted answer does, isn't good practice, nor is unnecessary recursion.

Comment: Thank you  for your `xy` mention i will read more about it try to improve it

Comment: @JSX why would you do that ? That’s not how it supposed to be done. Our imagination is very limited, which means you’ll get repeated names quite often the more files stored, the more files you get, the more time yow code will be hanging there finding a none used name. You supposed to set a uuid as name to the file and in yow db you need to store the original name, owner, mine type and which Eva you requiered, plus if you add a “human readable name” them hackers might be able to fetch them or so

Comment: Can you please improve your answer to a better approach as you see that it's a better practice

Comment: @Ernesto I'm confused now 